# Kafka Consumer poll (timeout: 0) but actually fetch the records back

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I use one thread to poll data, and the other thread to process data.
Since the processing takes longer time, so I want to limit the data size when it is becoming bigger and bigger. My plan is to poll ( timeout: 0 milliseconds) then it will return the record which is empty. However, the truth is that once every about 10 times, the poll(0) method will fetch the records which is full.

My question is,

1. Why will poll(0) sometimes fetch full records back? Even though most time it won't.
2. Is there any way to limit the poll?

PS: I tried consumer.pause() method. But since the consumer takes the partitions randomly. I don't know which partitions to pause. How do I know which partitions the consumer instance takes?

Comment: There is this comment: _before returning the fetched records, we can send off the next round of fetches and avoid block waiting for their responses to enable pipelining while the user is handling the fetched records_ in poll() method. From which looks like this is intended behaviour to return more records on poll(0). I wish I understand better what it really means. For the PS part - you can get partitions with `consumer.assignment()`.

Answer (score 0):

consumer.assignment() will return the Set of assigned partitions to your consumer. The max.poll.records setting determines the max number of ConsumerRecords to return, default 500. I guess poll(0) will only return records on a super busy system if the thread gets paused after making the request to kafka but before selecting for responses.